# Ist „Mensch“ geschlechtsneutral?

Tags: word-choice, gender

Kann das Subjekt im folgenden Beispiel eine Frau sein?

> Der moderne Mensch ist anders. Er hat wenig Zeit.

Wenn nicht, was wäre ein besseres Wort?

Comment: Aber aufgepasst auf den Artikel: „Das Mensch“ bezeichnet *immer* eine Frau/Mädchen (zumindest in den Regionen, in denen man das sagen darf).

Comment: @Debilski: Wusste ich nicht. Danke!

Comment: *Das Mensch* habe ich noch nie gehört. Ich wäre damit vorsichtig, bis man es von einem Einheimischen gehört hat.

Comment: Ich (geborener Österreicher) kenne 'das Mensch' auch, habe aber die Erfahrung gemacht, dass außerhalb der Gebirgsgegenden in Österreich und Süddeutschland kaum jemand damit etewas anzufangen wußte.

Comment: *Der* Mensch kann weiblich sein und *die* Spezies Mensch kann männliche Individuen beinhalten.

Comment: Wenn einem das alles zu (grammatikalisch) männlich wird, kann man ab und an „Person“ einwerfen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, kann es. Es ist das Wort der Wahl für solche Konstrukte.

Answer (score 5):

Mensch ist geschlechtsneutral.

Darüber hinaus ist die Konstruktion "der Mensch" wie im Beispielssatz immer eine allgemeine Aussage, die den Sprecher in eine distanzierte Beobachterposition setzt (die gerade in diesem Beispiel gar nicht der Fall sein kann).

Wenn wie hier die Einzahl mit bestimmtem Artikel für die Aussage über eine Gruppe verwendet wird, ist die Aussage meist ein Vorurteil oder zumindest sehr pauschalierend, da es impliziert, dass man alle modernen Menschen wie eine einzelne Person betrachten kann.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke es hat den Beiklang `der erwachsene Mensch`.

`Kinder` sind zwar nicht explizit ausgeschlossen, sondern mehr `einfach übersehen`.

Comment: Mmm, das mag manchmal so sein, aber nicht grundsätzlich. Dazu passt z.B. nicht: "Bei Gefahr fliegt der Vogel davon. Der Mensch kann das nicht."

Comment: Ja das trifft zu.